# Python Optimization: Using vector technique to find power of each matrix in an numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

3D numpy array `A` contains a series (in this example, I am choosing 3) of 2D numpy array `D` of shape `2 x 2`. The `D` matrix is as follows:

```
D = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

`A` is initialized and assigned as below:

```
idx = np.arange(3)
A = np.zeros((3,2,2))
A[idx,:,:] = D           # This gives A = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]],\
                         # [[1,2],[3,4]]]
                         # In mathematical notation: A = {D, D, D}
```

Now, essentially what I require after the execution of the codes is:

Mathematically, `A = {D^0, D^1, D^2} = {D0, D1, D2}`
where `D0 = [[1,0],[0,1]]`, `D1 = [[1,2],[3,4]]`, `D2=[[7,10],[15,22]]`

Is it possible to apply power to each matrix element in `A` without using a for-loop? I would be doing larger matrices with more in the series.

I had defined, `n = np.array([0,1,2])` # corresponding to powers 0, 1 and 2 and tried

`Result = np.power(A,n)` but I do not get the desired output.

Is there are an efficient way to do it?

Full code:

```
D = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
idx = np.arange(3)
A = np.zeros((3,2,2))
A[idx,:,:] = D           # This gives A = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]],\
                         # [[1,2],[3,4]]]
                         # In mathematical notation: A = {D, D, D}
n = np.array([0,1,2])
Result = np.power(A,n)   # ------> Not the desired output.
```

Comment: Can you explain the expected output? is This `D0 = [[1,0],[0,1]], D1 = [[1,2],[3,4]], D2=[[7,10],[15,22]]` the expected output? If so, that does not seem like a power function.

Comment: I want D0, D1, D2 within A with that result. Prior to applying power: A = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]]]. After application of power it should be A = [[[1,0],[0,1]],[[1,2],[3,4]],[[7,10],[15,22]]].

Comment: why does raising `[[1,2],[3,4]]` to zero turn it into `[[1,0],[0,1]]`. Should it not be `[[1,1],[1,1]]`? What is the logic of the operation?

Comment: No, it should turn out to be an identity matrix. In case of any scalar number, a(b^0) = a because b^0 = 1. It's the identity property. Likewise for matrix, any square matrix to the power 0 is identity matrix i.e. in this case [[1,0],[0,1]] (say this is B). So if you now multiply any matrix A with B (AB) you get A, which can be verified manually as well..

Comment: Ah i see, thanks for explaining

Answer (score 3):

A cumulative product exists in numpy, but not for matrices. Therefore, you need to make your own 'matcumprod' function. You can use np.dot for this, but np.matmul (or `@`) is specialized for matrix multiplication.

Since you state your powers always go from 0 to some_power, I suggest the following function:

```
def matcumprod(D, upto):
  Res = np.empty((upto, *D.shape), dtype=A.dtype)
  Res[0, :, :] = np.eye(D.shape[0])
  Res[1, :, :] = D.copy()
  for i in range(1,upto):
    Res[i, :, :] = Res[i-1,:,:] @ D

  return Res
```

By the way, a loop often times outperforms a built-in numpy function if the latter uses a lot of memory, so don't fret over it if your powers stay within bounds...

Answer (score 2):

Alright, i spent a lot of time on this problem but could not seem to find a vectorized solution in the way you'd like. So i would like to instead first propose a basic solution, and then perhaps an optimization if you require finding continuous powers.

The function you're looking for is called [`numpy.linalg.matrix_power`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_power.html#numpy.linalg.matrix_power)

```
import numpy as np

D = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
idx = np.arange(3)
A = np.zeros((3,2,2))
A[idx,:,:] = D           # This gives A = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[1,2],[3,4]],\
                         # [[1,2],[3,4]]]
                         # In mathematical notation: A = {D, D, D}
np.zeros(A.shape)
n = np.array([0,1,2])
result = [np.linalg.matrix_power(D, i) for i in n]
np.array(result)
#Output:
array([[[ 1,  0],
        [ 0,  1]],

       [[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 7, 10],
        [15, 22]]])
```

However, if you notice, you end up calculating multiple powers for the same base matrix. We could instead utilize the intermediate results and go from there, using [`numpy.linalg.multi_dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html#numpy.linalg.multi_dot)

```
def all_powers_arr_of_matrix(A): 
    result = np.zeros(A.shape)
    result[0] = np.linalg.matrix_power(A[0], 0)
    for i in range(1, A.shape[0]):
        result[i] = np.linalg.multi_dot([result[i - 1], A[i]])
    return result
    result = all_powers_arr_of_matrix(A)
#Output:
array([[[ 1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.]],

       [[ 7., 10.],
        [15., 22.]]])
```

Also, we can avoid creating the matrix A entirely, saving some time.

```
    def all_powers_matrix(D, *rangeargs): #end exclusive
        ''' Expects 2D matrix. 
        Use as all_powers_matrix(D, end) or
        all_powers_matrix(D, start, end)
        '''
        if len(rangeargs) == 1:
            start = 0
            end = rangeargs[0]
        elif len(rangeargs) == 2:
            start = rangeargs[0]
            end = rangeargs[1]
        else:
            print("incorrect args")
            return None
        result = np.zeros((end - start, *D.shape))
        result[0] = np.linalg.matrix_power(A[0], start)
        for i in range(start + 1, end):
            result[i] = np.linalg.multi_dot([result[i - 1], D])
        return result

            return result
result = all_powers_matrix(D, 3)
#Output:
array([[[ 1.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.]],

       [[ 7., 10.],
        [15., 22.]]])
```

Note that you'd need to add error handling if you decide to use these functions as-is.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to solve this. I am putting it for timeit test and I will brief you on the result.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate power of matrix `D`, one way could be to find the eigenvalues and right eigenvectors of it with [`np.linalg.eig`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html#numpy.linalg.eig) and then raise the power of the diagonal matrix as it is easier, then after some manipulation, you can use two [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html?highlight=einsum#numpy.einsum) to calculate `A`

```
#get eigvalues and eigvectors
eigval, eigvect = np.linalg.eig(D)

# to check how it works, you can do:
print (np.dot(eigvect*eigval,np.linalg.inv(eigvect)))
#[[1. 2.]
# [3. 4.]]
# so you get back on D

#use power as ufunc of outer with n on the eigenvalues to get all the one you want
arrp = np.power.outer( eigval, n).T

#apply_along_axis to create the diagonal matrix along the last axis
diagp = np.apply_along_axis( np.diag, axis=-1, arr=arrp)

#finally use two np.einsum to calculate with the subscript to get what you want
A = np.einsum('lij,jk -> lik',
              np.einsum('ij,kjl -> kil',eigvect,diagp), np.linalg.inv(eigvect)).round()
print (A)
print (A.shape)

#[[[ 1.  0.]
#  [-0.  1.]]
#
# [[ 1.  2.]
#  [ 3.  4.]]
#
# [[ 7. 10.]
#  [15. 22.]]]
#
#(3, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full solution, but there are some things I wanted to mention which are a bit too long for the comments.

You might first look into [addition chain exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation) if you are computing big powers of big matrices. This is basically asking how many matrix multiplications are required to compute `A^k` for a given `k`. For instance `A^5 = A(A^2)^2` so you need to only three matrix multiplies: `A^2` and `(A^2)^2` and `A(A^2)^2`. This might be the simplest way to gain some efficiency, but you will probably still have to use explicit loops.

Your question is also related to the problem of computing `Ax, A^2x, ... , A^kx` for a given `A` and `x`. This is an active area of research right now (search "matrix powers kernel"), since computing such a sequence efficiently is useful for parallel/communication avoiding Krylov subspace methods. If you're looking for a very efficient solution to your problem it might be worth looking into some of the results about this.